# Semantic analysis of natural language using convoluted neural network

Tags: nlp, conv-neural-network

I would like to analysis some documents and classify them, but there are a lot of negative, double negative in the sentence. What would be the best way to analyse such text

I have some documents as such

```
"It is unlikely to be a xxx" -> 0
"The chance of xxx is low" -> 0
"xxx is not impossible" -> 1
"xxx cannot be ruled out" -> 1
"Chance that it is other than xxx is low" -> 1
```

Obviously "bag of word" approach will not work. Need to have some sort of method to understand spatial relationship. 
Would a convoluted neural network help with analyzing this sort of text? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Although convolutional neural networks can be used for sequential data, the normal approach is to use a [recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) (RNN).

Modern RNNs such as [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) networks and [GRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit) networks have architectures which *remember* words earlier in the sentence.
Therefore, a model of this type should be able to associate arbitrarily many words with negative connotations over (reasonably) long sentences.

For an intro to implementing a text classification model, see [this guide for beginners](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction. I will look up your link